# Completely Reset Windows 10 Account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, reset

My issue is as follows:

I have a default user account ("Administrator") on a Windows 10 machine, a built in account that comes with the operating system. I'd like to reset this account (possibly not the right term, so let me explain): files, settings, file history, application preferences, applications/services/tasks installed by user's applications. Literally everything created by this account, I want to reset/delete it. Even if I have to manually do it, how can I do this? Nothing I've found covers this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you search? https://www.kapilarya.com/reset-built-in-administrator-account-in-windows-10 and other sites explain how.

Comment: Didn't see this anywhere, but thanks! I must've not used the right keywords for this one. I only saw resetting computer posts.